Grouping items in the bibliography with same (but multiple) authors
I was wondering how to group in the bibliography entries from coauthored papers with one author in common (of course, whenever there is an author in common between multiple entries).
More exactly, I mean:

Current setup:


– Expected result (sorry: they should be in chronological order):

This is my preamble concerning bibliography/code (nabib, bibtex, apalike –I use Texifier on Mac, as well as apalike-dashed.bst for dashes, which however still don't work the way I want):
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{shortbib}
@incollection{abelson_computer_1963,
    address = {New York},
    title = {Computer {Simulation} of “{Hot} {Cognition}”},
    booktitle = {Psychology's {New} {Frontier}: {Computer} {Simulation} of {Personality}},
    publisher = {Wiley},
    author = {Abelson, Robert P.},
    editor = {Tomkins, Silvan S. and Messick, Samuel},
    year = {1963},
    pages = {277--298},
}

@article{abelson_symbolic_1958,
    title = {Symbolic {Psycho}-{Logic}: {A} {Model} of {Attitudinal} {Cognition}},
    volume = {3},
    journal = {Behavioral Science},
    author = {Abelson, Robert P. and Rosenberg, Milton J.},
    year = {1958},
    pages = {1--13},
}

@article{abelson_modes_1959,
    title = {Modes of {Resolution} of {Belief} {Dilemmas}},
    volume = {3},
    number = {4},
    journal = {Journal of Conflict Resolution},
    author = {Abelson, Robert P.},
    year = {1959},
    note = {Publisher: Sage Publications Sage CA: Thousand Oaks, CA},
    pages = {343--352},
}

@incollection{rosenberg_analysis_1960,
    address = {New Haven},
    title = {An {Analysis} of {Cognitive} {Balancing}},
    booktitle = {Attitude {Organization} and {Change}: {An} {Analysis} of {Consistency} {Among} {Attitude} {Components}},
    publisher = {Yale University Press},
    author = {Rosenberg, Milton J. and Abelson, Robert P.},
    editor = {Rosenberg, Milton J. and Hovland, C. I. and McGuire, W. J. and Abelson, Robert. P. and Breehm, J. W.},
    year = {1960},
    pages = {112--163},
}

@article{abelson_computer_1965,
    title = {Computer {Simulation} of {Individual} {Belief} {Systems}},
    volume = {8},
    number = {9},
    journal = {American Behavioral Scientist},
    author = {Abelson, Robert P. and Carroll, J. Douglas},
    year = {1965},
    note = {Publisher: SAGE Publications Sage CA: Los Angeles, CA},
    pages = {24--30},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[square,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike-dashed}

\def\bibfont{\footnotesize}
\setcitestyle{aysep={}} 
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt plus 0.3ex}

\newcommand\cites[2][]{\citeauthor{#2}'s\ [\citeyear[#1]{#2}]}
\newcommand\citeauthors[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s}

\newcommand\citess[2][]{\citeauthor{#2}'\ [\citeyear[#1]{#2}]}
\newcommand\citeauthorss[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'}


\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\sortentry}[1]{%
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\uNAT@aux@sortentry{#1}}%
  \fi}
\newcommand*{\uNAT@aux@sortentry}{%
  \listgadd{\uNAT@bibsortlist}}
\newcommand*{\uNAT@bibsortlist}{}
\newcommand*{\uNAT@citekeys}{}
\newcommand*{\uNAT@writetocitelistsort}[1]{%
  \ifinlist{#1}{\uNAT@citekeys}
    {\ifdefvoid{\NAT@cite@list}
       {\def\NAT@cite@list{#1}}       {\expandafter\def\expandafter\NAT@cite@list\expandafter{\NAT@cite@list,#1}}%
     \listgadd{\uNAT@foundkeys}{#1}}
    {}}
\newcommand*{\uNAT@writetocitelistforgotten}[1]{%
  \ifinlist{#1}{\uNAT@foundkeys}
    {}
    {\ifdefvoid{\NAT@cite@list}
       {\def\NAT@cite@list{#1}}
       {\expandafter\def\expandafter\NAT@cite@list\expandafter{\NAT@cite@list,#1}}}}
\newcommand*{\uNAT@sortcites}[1]{%
  \let\NAT@cite@list\@empty
  \let\uNAT@citekeys\@empty
  \let\uNAT@foundkeys\@empty
  \forcsvlist{\listadd{\uNAT@citekeys}}{#1}%
  \forlistloop{\uNAT@writetocitelistsort}{\uNAT@bibsortlist}%
  \forlistloop{\uNAT@writetocitelistforgotten}{\uNAT@citekeys}%
}
\def\NAT@citex%
  [#1][#2]#3{%
  \NAT@reset@parser
  \NAT@sort@cites{#3}%
  \uNAT@sortcites{#3}%<- this is new
  \NAT@reset@citea
  \@cite{\let\NAT@nm\@empty\let\NAT@year\@empty
    \@for\@citeb:=\NAT@cite@list\do
    {\@safe@activestrue
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
     \@safe@activesfalse
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}{\@citea%
       {\reset@font\bfseries ?}\NAT@citeundefined
                 \PackageWarning{natbib}%
       {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}\def\NAT@date{}}%
     {\let\NAT@last@nm=\NAT@nm\let\NAT@last@yr=\NAT@year
      \NAT@parse{\@citeb}%
      \ifNAT@longnames\@ifundefined{bv@\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}{%
        \let\NAT@name=\NAT@all@names
        \global\@namedef{bv@\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}{}}{}%
      \fi
     \ifNAT@full\let\NAT@nm\NAT@all@names\else
       \let\NAT@nm\NAT@name\fi
     \ifNAT@swa\ifcase\NAT@ctype
       \if\relax\NAT@date\relax
         \@citea\NAT@hyper@{\NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}\NAT@date}%
       \else
         \ifx\NAT@last@nm\NAT@nm\NAT@yrsep
            \ifx\NAT@last@yr\NAT@year
              \def\NAT@temp{{?}}%
              \ifx\NAT@temp\NAT@exlab\PackageWarningNoLine{natbib}%
               {Multiple citation on page \thepage: same authors and
               year\MessageBreak without distinguishing extra
               letter,\MessageBreak appears as question mark}\fi
              \NAT@hyper@{\NAT@exlab}%
            \else\unskip\NAT@spacechar
              \NAT@hyper@{\NAT@date}%
            \fi
         \else
           \@citea\NAT@hyper@{%
             \NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}%
             \hyper@natlinkbreak{%
               \NAT@aysep\NAT@spacechar}{\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb
             }%
             \NAT@date
           }%
         \fi
       \fi
     \or\@citea\NAT@hyper@{\NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}}%
     \or\@citea\NAT@hyper@{\NAT@date}%
     \or\@citea\NAT@hyper@{\NAT@alias}%
     \fi \NAT@def@citea
     \else
       \ifcase\NAT@ctype
        \if\relax\NAT@date\relax
          \@citea\NAT@hyper@{\NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}}%
        \else
         \ifx\NAT@last@nm\NAT@nm\NAT@yrsep
            \ifx\NAT@last@yr\NAT@year
              \def\NAT@temp{{?}}%
              \ifx\NAT@temp\NAT@exlab\PackageWarningNoLine{natbib}%
               {Multiple citation on page \thepage: same authors and
               year\MessageBreak without distinguishing extra
               letter,\MessageBreak appears as question mark}\fi
              \NAT@hyper@{\NAT@exlab}%
            \else
              \unskip\NAT@spacechar
              \NAT@hyper@{\NAT@date}%
            \fi
         \else
           \@citea\NAT@hyper@{%
             \NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}%
             \hyper@natlinkbreak{\NAT@spacechar\NAT@@open\if*#1*\else#1\NAT@spacechar\fi}%
               {\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}%
             \NAT@date
           }%
         \fi
        \fi
       \or\@citea\NAT@hyper@{\NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}}%
       \or\@citea\NAT@hyper@{\NAT@date}%
       \or\@citea\NAT@hyper@{\NAT@alias}%
       \fi
       \if\relax\NAT@date\relax
         \NAT@def@citea
       \else
         \NAT@def@citea@close
       \fi
     \fi
     }}\ifNAT@swa\else\if*#2*\else\NAT@cmt#2\fi
     \if\relax\NAT@date\relax\else\NAT@@close\fi\fi}{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\def\NAT@yrsep{;}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\citep{abelson_computer_1963,abelson_symbolic_1958,abelson_modes_1959,rosenberg_analysis_1960,abelson_computer_1965}

\bibliography{shortbib}
\end{document}

I don't want to switch to different bibliography styles or to Biblatex, because it's for me very impractical.
I hope you can help me!

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your given code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Thank you! I tried, hope it's everything good.
